# The syntax to use in the input

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have error in `='@`

> unterminated string constant

```
<input class="blue" type="button" onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action("Index", "Home", Model.RouteData))';" value="Index"/>
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input class="blue" type="button" onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action(\"Index\", \"Home\", Model.RouteData))';" value="Index"/>
```

This should work. But you should really limit the usage of inline CSS/JS.

Something like this should be better.

HTML

```
<input id="button" class="blue" type="button" value="Index"/>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick= function(){
   location.href='@(Url.Action("Index", "Home", Model.RouteData))';
}
```

Comment: Why this worked `<button class="blue" type="button" onClick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", Model.RouteData)';">Index</button>`

Answer (score 0):

String constants must be enclosed within a pair of quotation marks.

Try this-

```
<input class="blue" type="button" onclick="location.href='@(Url.Action('"Index"', '"Home"', Model.RouteData))';" value="Index"/>
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong there, bud. You'd need some more quotation marks and concatenation to make it work like that. `location.href='@(Url.Action('+'"Index"'+', '+'"Home"'+', Model.RouteData))';`